# Python-- Mean and Standard Deviation over groups of columns

Tags: python, numpy, std, mean

I am using Python and I have a black and white .FIT image file that is 2048 x 2048 pixels and each pixel has a single value. I need to find the standard deviation of the pixel values for the first 64 columns. By this i mean, i need to consider every pixel value in the first 64 columns then use those vales to find the standard deviation. I know how to find the standard deviation of each column, but i don't know how to do it for groups of columns. Essentially, after i can find if for the first 64 rows, I need to to it for the rest of the picture as well, meaning for 32 groups of 64 columns. I hope this question isn't too confusing. Thank you!

Comment: do you need a special library to read a .fit image? can you just use PIL?

Comment: I use pyfits and define the image as an array

array=pyfits.getdata('filename')

which puts the pixel values into a 2 dimensional array of those pixelvalues, So essentially I am just asking how to manipulate the array

Comment: and what do you want to grab from those pixel values?

Comment: I want to find the Mean and Standard Deviation of all of the pixel values located in the first 64 columns of the array

Comment: sorry that I am not understanding, but the values in the two dimensional array are RGB values?

Comment: can you post an example of your data?

Comment: Im sorry, i should be more clear, the image is in black and white, so each pixel has a single numerical value, that can be positive or negative

Comment: can you post an example of your data? what is it using? a list, or a numpy array?

Comment: if you can get a list of all 64 columns, you can do something like numpy.concatenate(lists_of_lists)

Comment: it is a 2 dimensional numpy array...the data is too large, but essentially it would help if this could be answered. If i have a 2-dimensional numpy array where the columns are 1,2,3...4,5,6...7,8,9, i am trying to find the mean value of 1,2,4,5,7,8, where i exclude 3,6 and 9 from my calculations

[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
{7,8,9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as a numpy array as such:

```
include numpy as np    
np.std(array)
```

Example of grabbing parts of array:

```
a = [1 2 3]
a[0:1] = [1]
a[0:2] = [1 2]
```

Also for 2D (or higher) array,

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
b = np.array(a)
print b[:,:3]
[[1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]]
```

Comment: I do plan on using this function, however, the image is in the form of a 2-D array and i'm not sure how to specify to find the standard deviation of only parts of the array. numpy.std(array) would give me the standard deviation of the whole thing

Comment: It was a point in the right direction. You can always grab parts of your array with `array[start:end]` or wherever you need (as shown in answer).

Comment: if it is a 2 dimensional array, how do i select, lets say, the first 6 columns?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
np.std(np.concatenate(your_data),axis=0)
```

oh and if you want to select specific columns, replace your_data with your_data[[1,2,3,5,6,8,9]] or whatever you want. to make is easier you can do something like your_data[range(1,something)+[6,2,4]]